# Create ChildWindow in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to create a Modal window using a dialog service for WPF.  I have found this example and am trying to create and learn

[Modal dialogs with MVVM](http://blog.roboblob.com/2010/01/19/modal-dialogs-with-mvvm-and-silverlight-4/)

I would like to create a ChildWindow in WPF.  I have added the Extended WPF toolkit and added it as a reference.  What I can't understand is how I make an entire window a ChildWindow.  In my code below I can add the Extended toolkit namespace to the window but I can't make the entire window a ChildWindow.  How can I make a ChildWindow?

```
<Window x:Class="ModalPopupWindows.ErrorWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    Title="ErrorWindow" Height="300" Width="300">   

    <custom:ChildWindow>

    </custom:ChildWindow>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no true way to make a window a "child", but you can, and should set the new windows "owner".

```
        var win = new MainWindow();
        win.Owner = this;
        win.DataContext = this.DataContext;
        win.Closed += (() =>
        {
            //do this processing after window has been closed
        });
        win.ShowDialog(); //instead of ".Show();" this makes the window modal
```

AFAIK this is the correct way. Of course you can add handlers for closed events multiple ways, this is just an example. Also consider setting datacontext you need - this example passes parent window's datacontext to child's/modal directly.

Comment: They just need to set the Owner property of the Window. There's also ShowDialog method that could be used for a modal window.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This one
<Grid>
<Button x:Name="btnclick" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

.cs Page

```
btnclick.Click +=new RoutedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ChildWindow chldWindow = new ChildWindow();
            MessageBox.Show(chldWindow.Getmessage());
            chldWindow.ShowDialog();
        });
```